# Dropbox: computer name changed

Tags: dropbox

I use dropbox on multiple computers.  One of my computers was recently removed and the computer name was changed.

What will happen to all of the local dropbox files on this box?

Will they still be accessible to the person who has control of the new box?

Will they still sync up to main dropbox account if the computer name was changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen to all of the local dropbox files on this box?

They remain on the computer.

> Will they still be accessible to the person who has control of the new
>   box?

Yes assuming that the new user has adequate privileges.

> Will they still sync up to main dropbox account if the computer name
>   was changed?

AFAIK, yes because the account is still linked. Someone would have to login to let dropbox run and sync though.